# javascript based progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, indicator

I am curious how can a javascript (or also benefiting from jquery) based progress indicator such can be developed:

[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3295/dealindicator.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3295/dealindicator.png)

My first idea is something such as:

```
function drawBar(total,sofar){
.........................

}
```

where it consumes the max number(20 in our case) and sofar (15 for the picture).

But how can it be implemented?

Is there any jquery based plugin to achieve this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done with CSS, by creating a `div` the total size of your progressbar, and then having another `div` child of that which has a percentage width of how much needs to be filled.

You can style the `div`s anyway you want. You likely want to style the inner div with `background-color`, or `background-image` & `background-repeat`. It can be a solid colour, a gradient, or a banded pattern, which seems to be rather popular.

Have you Google'd for jQuery plugins? They are fairly easy to find. Here's one for example: http://t.wits.sg/jquery-progress-bar/